# Why does this expression equal NaN, but equal a valid answer when defined somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, object, field

So I'm writing a game on JS Canvas and I'm making my own GUI from scratch. To do so, I made a `button` object with fields `x, y, width, height` and `intersects(click_event)`. For some reason, when I directly put this expression for `x`, it returns `NaN` even though the expression works everywhere else.

It's just a simple game on Canvas. I know I could probably use some dirty trick to work around it, but I want to keep my code clean. I just don't understand why this wouldn't work.

```
var button = {
    height:80, 
    width:200, 
    x:canvas.width/2 - this.width/2, //this is the problem
    y:200, 
    //other stuff
};



console.log(button.x);  //this prints "NaN"
console.log(canvas.width/2 - button.width/2);  //prints correct num
```

The canvas width is 1000, so 1000 / 2 - 200 / 2 should equal 400, which it does when called inside `console.log`.

But when I put it inside `button.x` it evaluates to `NaN`.

Comment: `this.width` must be an issue. While constructing the object, you are accessing another property, that doesn't look right

Comment: `this.` is not the `this` you think this is

Comment: You need to write a get method to do the calucation for you, have a look at the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access/reference a property within a object during initialization.

So this will never work:

```
var myObject = {
  height: 2
  doubleHeight: 2 * this.height 
}
```

One solution would be to add the poperty after you have initialized the object. Your code would like this:

```
var button = {
    height:80, 
    width:200, 
    y:200, 
    //other stuff
};
button.x = canvas.width/2 - button.width/2
```

Another solution would be to wrap inside function

```
function createButton(height, width, canvasWidth) {
  return {
    height: height,
    width: width,
    y: width,
    x: canvasWidth/2 - width/2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using constructor function

```
var button = new function() {
    this.height=80; 
    this.width=200;
    this.x = canvas.width/2 - this.width/2;
    this.y=200; 
}
```